# SQL Max of Multiple Columns in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: sql, max, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm looking to measure the maximum date values of multiple columns in SQL for Marketing Cloud. Unfortunately Marketing Cloud lacks the built in functions for other answers I have seen across the forums (greatest, unpivot, cross-apply). Is there a way I can do this without using multiple nested CASE WHENS?

In simple terms

```
Select ID, Date1, Date2, Date3, MaxDate
From TableA
```

I've tried multiple other methods, but SFMC lack some of the built-in functions for an easy solution.

Comment: Just to a notice, you don't need nested cases. You can use `case when d1>=d2 and d1>=d3 then d1 when d2>=d3 then d2 else d3 end`

Comment: SFMC does support more functions than you might think.  PIVOT and UNPIVOT are now supported in Query Activities.  Query Studio is not the place to test them.

Comment: Thank you for the replies  - I have got it working on the case when you suggested @markalex, this seems to do the trick although it is fairly complex as I have 7 date columns to verify!

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I attempted your way first (you're right query studio is not a great place to test this!) but it wasn't returning the max value as I was expecting, just seemed to return a random value, not the max. Not sure if there is anything obviously wrong with this code? `SELECT  ID,
        MAX(dDate) As Most_Recent_Activity
       
FROM    Test_Data_Extension UNPIVOT ( dDate FOR nDate IN (Date1, Date2,  Date3, Date4,  Date5)) as u
GROUP BY 
ID`

Comment: The Unpivot would be my preference as would be easier to maintain.